# Automatically reopen android/ios app after x minutes

Tags: android, ios, architecture, timeout, mdm

We're building an app that will be installed on smartphones and displayed on a desk. The user need to be able to close the app and use the device, but when he does not use the device the app should move to the front automatically after X minutes.

Here is the catch: we need to support new devices for the coming 3 years and the user should not be able to close/kill the process.

**Android**: We found that we could use the permission BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN to make the process unkillable. However it will be deprecated soon and we have no idea how long it will remain functional.

**iOS**: We found no solution

Does anybody have a workaround/solution or does somebody know how much longer they will support the BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission?

I know it seems like something fishy, but it's actually intended for distribution internally via our company MDM and it makes sense in the context we are using it for.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you can either use the AlarmManager, or a JobScheduler or a Foreground Service...

I won't recommend a Foreground Service as it will always be visible to the user in the notification panel & would make your App look suspicious!
For AlarmManager / Job Scheduler part, you can use this library - 
https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure: if we use a job scheduler via WorkManager (google) or android-job (your link), it will still schedule and run even when you kill the app? Or does the app also need to be running (=open or in background) in order for it to work?

Comment: @JNDPNT 1) afaik, None of them would work if your app is killed by system or by user (force stop)... 2) Your app has to be opened once to start job schedulers, & they work in background :)

Comment: If we open the app once and the user clicks on the hardware button to show the open apps and swipes it away. Does it qualify as "kill" or will it keep alive the schedulers?